# Changing Menu Fonts Design

Tags: menus

I am using the 2011 theme and I would like to make the font that appears on the primary menu bigger and more stylish, is it possible for me to achieve this and if so, how to I go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really a pure CSS and HTML question and not specifically WordPress.

It's best to learn to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to view and work with the CSS and HTML in your theme and then make those changes to theme files, such as style.css.